# Google Drive Update Permissions to Owner

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update) to test updating permissions. Using the correct fileId and permissionId, I am able to update the given user's permission to either **reader** or **writer** but when I try to update to **owner** I receive a 500 Internal Server Error.

Note: I am able to recreate the same issue using the Google Client Library for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive Files can only have one owner so giving a user owner access to the file reduces the current owner's permissions to writer and transfers ownership to the new user (meaning it counts against the new user's quota). Google Drive Files can only be transferred between users in the same Google Apps instance. Attempting to grant a user owner rights across Google Apps instances or with consumer (gmail.com) accounts and non-Docs-native files will result in this 500 error.

Google describes how file ownership can be changed in their [help article](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en). The API follows the same limitations as the UI.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there anyway that a "Super Admin" of a Google Apps for Business domain would have more access? I am aware of how to [impersonate users](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation)

Comment: Super Admins authenticated as themselves do not have access to files they aren't shared on and can't change ownership of files they don't already own. They basically don't have any rights over what a regular user does. You'll need to use impersonation (which any super-admin has rights to setup) in order to get full access to all files for all users.